How to keep rows with the same value in a column together when sorting
I'm coding a larger project that will automatically sort a table ("Table2") by the values in different columns, but I want to create an exception where rows with the same value in column D are always kept next to each other. There's definitely multiple issues with what I have written but it's a starting point. Rows Dim grpRange As String: grpRange = "A"&first&":J"&last and Rows(first:last).Group are currently showing up as red and when run, I'm getting a compile error the first time Rows(firstPos).Insert tries to run, and I'm getting an error that the program is running out of stack space.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D3:D2000")) Is Nothing Then
        With Sheets("Sheet1")
            Dim wo As String
            Dim tb2 As ListObject
            Set tb2 = .ListObjects("Table2")
            Dim dupes() As Variant
            Dim t As Integer: t = 0
            Dim count As Integer: c = 2
            Dim newPos As Integer
            Dim Occurrences As Integer
            For Each rw In tb2.DataBodyRange.Rows    ' Iterate through each element.
                count = count + 1
                If rw.Cells(4).Value = ActiveCell.Value Then
                    If Occurrences = 0 Then
                        Occurrences = Occurrences + 1
                        Dim firstPos As Integer: firstPos = rw.Cells(4).Row
                    Else
                        Occurrences = Occurrences + 1
                        Rows(count).Cut
                        Rows(firstPos).Insert
                        newPos = firstPos - 1
                        ReDim dupes(0 To t)
                        dupes(t) = Rows(newPos).Row
                        t = t + 1
                    End If
                End If

                If Occurrences > 1 Then
                    Dim first As Integer: first = dupes(0)
                    Dim last As Integer: last = dupes(t)
                    Dim grpRange As String: grpRange = "A"&first&":J"&last
                    Rows(first:last).Group
                End If
            Next
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Is trying to group the rows like this even the right approach?
EDIT: Th reason why I'm not just sorting by Column D is that what the end user wants is the table to be auto-sorted by column c as primary and column e as secondary (this code is already implemented and works fine), however sometimes there are multiple rows with the same values in column D (for context it's the order #) but different values in Column E and he wants those kept together. The problem with just sorting col C>col D>col E is that the sorting in col E would then be totally messed up for all of the entries with no duplicates in column D.

The simplest way to ensure that rows with the same value in column D remain grouped together is to sort the table with column D as the primary / first key.

FYI ActiveCell could be anywhere on the worksheet so I would not use that for anything...

For syntax errors (red line): 1.String concatenation operator needs separated from stirng with spaces (before, after) in VBA.  2. Rows(first & ":" & last).Group

Guess that the c variable should be count here:  Dim count As Integer: c = 2.  At the moment your first use of count sets it to 1:  count = count + 1

Thanks for the syntax help everyone! @taller that's what I tried at first, but the problem is that what the end user wants is the table to be auto-sorted by column c as primary and column e as secondary (this code is already implemented and works fine), however sometimes there are multiple rows with the same values in column D  (for context it's the order #) but different values in Column E and he wants those kept together. The problem with just sorting col C>col D>col E is that the sorting in col E would then be totally messed up for all of the entries with no duplicates in column D.

I recognize that the structure of the data I'm working with here is very not great, trying to implement better tracking for a very old system

Is sheet Sheet1 the sheet whose module contains this code? Is there data to the right of the table? Is the operating system Windows? I need this information since I would use the Dictionary object to easily write a sort sequence to the column located two columns to the right of the table to sort the data by it before removing it.

@VBasic2008 Yes Sheet1 contains this code and the OS is Windows 10. Not 100% if this is what you want but the table is from A:J and there is no content on the sheet other than the table

That's the information I asked for. Thx. Need a couple of hours though.
